# error: 'myMD2' does not name a type

Tags: c++, opengl

I've recently gained interest in C++ and OpenGL programming, I've tried several types of code and they all run smoothly... then i was asked to test this code but for some reason i get errors all the time... and now i am lost on what i should do...

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //include only needed libraries
#include <windows.h>    //include necessary windows definitions
#include <GL/glut.h>        //include openGL functionality
#include "myMD2.h"

BOOL stillActive;       //status checker
BOOL Keys[256];         //different keys that the user can click on
HDC global_Hdc;         //Handle Device Context

int winWidth;
int winHeight;

myMD2 *myMD2;


LRESULT CALLBACK myWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uint, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

void mySetPixel (HDC pixHDC);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hThisTust, LPSTR lpArgs,int iCmd)
{
    HWND myHwnd;
    MSG myMsg;
    WNDCLASSEX myWndClass;
    static TCHAR myClass[] = TEXT("myclass");
    myWndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    myWndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    myWndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    myWndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    myWndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    myWndClass.hIconSm = NULL;
    myWndClass.hInstance = hThisTust;
    myWndClass.lpfnWndProc = myWndProc;
    myWndClass.lpszClassName = myClass;
    myWndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    myWndClass.style =
        CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&myWndClass)){
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("cannot register class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return(0);
    }
    myHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, myClass, NULL, WS_POPUP,0,0,1024,768,NULL, NULL, hThisTust, NULL);
    if(!myHwnd){
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("cannot create window"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return(0);
    }
    ShowWindow(myHwnd, iCmd);
    UpdateWindow(myHwnd);
    stillActive = TRUE;

    while(stillActive){ //Entering game loop
        if(PeekMessage(&myMsg, NULL, 0,0, PM_REMOVE) == WM_QUIT)
            stillActive = FALSE;
        else{
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glViewport(0,0,1024,768);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(45.0f,1024/768,1.0f,1000.0f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            myMD2 -> draw();
            SwapBuffers(global_Hdc);

            TranslateMessage(&myMsg);
            DispatchMessage(&myMsg);
        }
    }
    return myMsg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK myWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    HDC myHdc;
    HGLRC myHglrc; //Handle Graphics Library Resource Context
    switch(msg){
        case WM_CREATE:
            myHdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            global_Hdc = myHdc;
            mySetPixel(myHdc);
            myHglrc = wglCreateContext(myHdc);
            wglMakeCurrent(myHdc, myHglrc);
            myMD2 = new MYMD2();
            myMD2->setup();
            myMD2->angle += 180;
            myMD2->obj3D.SetAnim(1);
            return(0);
            break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            Keys[wParam] = TRUE;
            if (Keys['Q']) //Keys[VK_ESCAPE]
                stillActive = FALSE;
            if (Keys[VK_SPACE]) //If the spacebar is pressed
                myMD2->obj3D.SetAnim(6);
            return(0);
            break;
        case WM_KEYUP:
            if (Keys[VK_SPACE])
                myMD2->obj3D.SetAnim(1);
            Keys[wParam] = FALSE;
                return(0);
            break;
        case WM_SIZE:
             winWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
             winHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
             if (winHeight == 0)
                winHeight = 1;
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glViewport(0,0,1024,768);
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                gluPerspective(45.0f,1024/768,1.0f,1000.0f);
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glLoadIdentity();
            return(0);
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            if(myHdc){
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, myHdc);
            }
            if(myHglrc){
                wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
                wglDeleteContext(myHglrc);
            }
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return(0);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            if(myHdc){
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, myHdc);
            }
            if(myHglrc){
                wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
                wglDeleteContext(myHglrc);
            }
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return(0);
            break;
        default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
}
void mySetPixel(HDC myPixHdc){
    int mySelected;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER |
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        32,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,
        16,
        0,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,0,0,0
    };
    mySelected = ChoosePixelFormat(myPixHdc, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(myPixHdc, mySelected, &pfd);
}
```

myMD2.h

```
#ifndef MY_MD2_H
#define MY_MD2_H

typedef void* md2_t;
md2_t md2_open(const char *filename);
void md2_close(md2_t h);
void md2_desc(md2_t h);
void md2_frame_sample(md2_t _h);
void md2_draw(md2_t h);

#endif
```

Comment: `myMD2` seems used as both name of type and name of variable. It is too confusing, so consider changing the name of **one** of them.

Comment: Would you mind showing as the content of "myMD2.h"?

Comment: Actually it was not given to me along with the code... so i tried looking on the internet and found this on github                                                                                                           #ifndef MY_MD2_H
    #define MY_MD2_H

    typedef void* md2_t;

     md2_t md2_open(const char *filename);
     void md2_close(md2_t h);
     void md2_desc(md2_t h);

     void md2_frame_sample(md2_t _h);
     void md2_draw(md2_t h);

      #endif

Comment: Yes, the compiler says that 'myMD2' does not name a type because `myMD2` is undefined and does not name a type.

Comment: The code you found on github looks completely unrelated to what your code is doing. I think you've just found something similarly named. Ask whoever asked you to test that code to provide the code that's needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question cannot be solved here. Only the original author of the code can provide information on which header file should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The headerfile `myMD2.h` does not define a class or struct called `myMD2`. From the rest of your code I would guess that you have downloaded the wrong header file.